# adding overload to DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to add the password to my string connection in the constructor of my DBContext like this

```
public partial class Control : DbContext
{
    public Control(string conexion): base(crearConexion(conexion))
    {

    }

    public static String crearConexion(string nombreConexion) 
    {
        string conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nombreConexion].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conexion);
        sqlBuilder.Password = "somepassword";
        return sqlBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

But It throws this exception 
   `system.argumentexception keyword not supported 'metadata'`

Why am I doing wrong??

Comment: It sounds to me simply like the EF string isn't *really* in the right format for SqlConnectionStringBuilder, so that approach is unsuirable.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation or approach that I can take, to add the password to the string connection??

Comment: not really, I'm afraid - I'm not a big EF user, so I'm not familiar with the nuances of the connection-strings. I *do* recall that they tend to be very large and ugly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

If you look at an EF connection string (check your app.config file), you'll see the sql server connection string is part of it, but also that there is additional information, which the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` can't parse:

```
metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=Test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;
```